# Why would the .text section of my object file be empty?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, ros

## Question

I'm compiling the following code using catkin_make. I have a c file `schedule_wrappers.c` and two c++ files `deadline_thread.cpp`, `stepper_motor.cpp` that are being used to create an executable in cmake with the following line:

`add_executable(stepper_motor src/stepper_motor.cpp src/deadline_thread.cpp src/schedule_wrappers.c)`

The `stepper_motor.cpp` file produces a "reasonable" `.o` file (the objdump produces output I would expect), but when cmake gets to the link step it says:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/stepper_motor.dir/src/stepper_motor.cpp.o: in function `StepperMotorTB6600::run()':
/home/spovilus/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/include/stepper_motor_TB6600.hpp:73: undefined reference to `wrapper_sched_yield'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/stepper_motor.dir/src/stepper_motor.cpp.o: in function `Motor::Motor(int, int)':
/home/spovilus/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/include/motor.hpp:43: undefined reference to `DeadlineThread::DeadlineThread(int, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/stepper_motor.dir/src/stepper_motor.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTI5Motor[_ZTI5Motor]+0x18): undefined reference to `typeinfo for DeadlineThread'
```

I tried to objdump the filed with `objdump -t ./build/beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/stepper_motor.dir/src/schedule_wrappers.c.o` and got:

```
./build/beginner_tutorials/CMakeFiles/stepper_motor.dir/src/schedule_wrappers.c.o:     file format elf64-littleaarch64

SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 schedule_wrappers.c
0000000000000000 l    d  .text  0000000000000000 .text
0000000000000000 l    d  .data  0000000000000000 .data
0000000000000000 l    d  .bss   0000000000000000 .bss
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_info    0000000000000000 .debug_info
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_abbrev  0000000000000000 .debug_abbrev
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_aranges 0000000000000000 .debug_aranges
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_line    0000000000000000 .debug_line
0000000000000000 l    d  .debug_str     0000000000000000 .debug_str
0000000000000000 l    d  .note.GNU-stack        0000000000000000 .note.GNU-stack
0000000000000000 l    d  .comment       0000000000000000 .comment
```

and I'm very confused as to why the .text section is empty.

The compiler command `cd /home/spovilus/catkin_ws/build/beginner_tutorials && /usr/bin/cc -DROSCONSOLE_BACKEND_LOG4CXX -DROS_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=1 -DROS_PACKAGE_NAME=\"beginner_tutorials\" -I/home/spovilus/catkin_ws/devel/include -I/home/spovilus/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/include -I/opt/ros/noetic/include -I/opt/ros/noetic/share/xmlrpcpp/cmake/../../../include/xmlrpcpp -I/home/spovilus/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/yaml-cpp/include -I/home/spovilus/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/boost/units/include  -O2 -g -DNDEBUG   -o CMakeFiles/stepper_motor.dir/src/schedule_wrappers.c.o   -c /home/spovilus/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/schedule_wrappers.c` emits warnings:

```
/home/spovilus/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/schedule_wrappers.c: In function ‘wrapper_sched_set_deadline’:
/home/spovilus/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/schedule_wrappers.c:35:7: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘perror’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   35 |       perror("Unable to get scheduler attributes");
      |       ^~~~~~
/home/spovilus/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/stepper_motor.cpp: In function ‘void positionCallback(const ConstPtr&)’:
/home/spovilus/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/stepper_motor.cpp:34:23: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘const ConstPtr’ {aka ‘const boost::shared_ptr<const beginner_tutorials::RelativePosition_<std::allocator<void> > >’} [-Wformat=]
   34 |     printf("position %d\n",position);
      |                      ~^
      |                       |
      |                       int
```

so I have to assume it'd doing something.

### Source code

```
/**
 * @file schedule_wrappers.c
 * @author Sam Povilus (povilus@povil.us)
 * @brief A file to wrap Linux Scheduler calls
 * @version 0.1
 * @date 2023-01-07
 *
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2023
 *
 */

#include <linux/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <linux/sched/types.h>


#include "schedule_wrappers.h"

static int wrapper_sched_getattr(pid_t pid, struct sched_attr *attr,
                         unsigned int size, unsigned int flags)
{
    return syscall(__NR_sched_getattr, pid, attr, size, flags);
}


static int wrapper_sched_set_deadline(int deadline)
{
    struct sched_attr attr;
    int ret = wrapper_sched_getattr(0, &attr, sizeof(attr), 0);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
      perror("Unable to get scheduler attributes");
      // throw scheduler_exception;
    }
    attr.sched_policy = SCHED_DEADLINE;
    attr.sched_deadline = deadline;
    return syscall(__NR_sched_setattr, 0, attr, 0);
}

static int wrapper_sched_set_runtime(int runtime)
{
    struct sched_attr attr;
    int ret = wrapper_sched_getattr(0, &attr, sizeof(attr), 0);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
      perror("Unable to get scheduler attributes");
      // throw scheduler_exception;
    }
    attr.sched_policy = SCHED_DEADLINE;
    attr.sched_runtime = runtime;
    return syscall(__NR_sched_setattr, 0, attr, 0);
}



static int wrapper_sched_yield()
{
    return syscall(__NR_sched_yield);
}
```

### cc version

```
$ /usr/bin/cc --version
cc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why would the .text section of my object file be empty?

Because all your functions are static, they are optimized out.

> undefined reference to `wrapper_sched_yield'

If you want the function to be externally visible, remove `static`. Also note `extern "C"` needed between C <-> C++ interoperability.

> warning: implicit declaration of function ‘perror’

You did not include stdio.h

> warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘const ConstPtr’ {aka ‘const boost::shared_ptr<const beginner_tutorials::RelativePosition_std::allocator<void > >’}

No idea what you are expecting here to happen. The code is invalid, you can't `printf` a `boost::shared_ptr`.

Comment: And now I feel incredibly dumb, I was converting this code from a C++ class to c code and had those wrappers as static for some reason only history knows. the static removal was what I was missing. Thanks!